# Phantom edges created on object when rendered

Tags: eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

I modeled a microchip and I'm trying to do a render of it rotating in Eevee and am using depth of field to give it a realistic effect. However, I notice that these strange edges appear and move as the model rotates, depending on the angle of the chip, that aren't actually there. It looks like another piece of geometry, but there isn't anything there. I've also noticed that if I zoom the viewport or camera in they disappear. Any ideas what's causing this and how I can fix them?

[image]

I remodeled another chip just to see if I could fix the issue (and I thought I could make a better model) and I've noticed the issue has returned.

[image]

Then I zoom in my viewport or my camera and they go away.

[image]

Comment: You may have a conflict between the almost-orthographic view and depth of field. Are you fully orthographic or is your focal length just huge ?

Comment: I have my camera set for Orthographic.Clip start is set to 0.001m. Focus distance is set to 9.4m. F-stop 4. Blades 8. Rotation 0°. Ratio 2000

Comment: Do you really have an object 1mm from your camera ? Looks like it's not the case at all. Try increase Clip start (in other words, reducing the Clip start-end range).

Comment: I've increased the clip start and it seems to push back the "phantom edge" along with the depth of field. Ideally I'm trying to keep the middle of the chip in focus as I plan to put a logo there. I also tried switching from Orthographic to Perspective and the weird edge still persists. Ideally, I'm trying to stick with orthographic. I'd be open to changing any of the other camera parameters, I just landed on this because of how it looks. Trying to have the shallow depth of field look, but not so shallow it'll obscure the logo or eventually make seeing the internals of the chip too difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. Eevee is doing a lot of guessing compared to Cycles, it may originate there, or not. We probably would need your blend files with https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: I think I found a solution! Basically, I just increased the clip start as you recommended, and then re-adjusted the F-stop and focal distance to each a similar effect. It seems to removed the weird edge. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Clip start and end are quite important and should be as small a range as possible. Your welcome !